# How display output command and pipe it to next command?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, tee

I would like to dispay the ouput (STDOUT) and also pipe to the next command. I know "tee" to display the result and write to a file, but instead to write to a file, I want to pipe to another command.

Example :

```
$ command1 --option1 --option2 | MAGICCOMMAND | jq -e '.returnCode'
```

I would have the output from "command1 --option1 --option2" and "jq -e ..."

Answer (score 7):

In the `bash` shell, you could use `tee` with a process substitution like this:

```
command1 --option1 --option2 | tee >( jq -e '.returnCode' )
```

This would write the output of `command1` to `tee`, which would duplicate it to standard output and also to the standard input of `jq`.

You could also do

```
command1 --option1 --option2 | tee /dev/stderr | jq -e '.returnCode'
```

which would put the output of `command1` onto the *standard error stream*, while piping its duplicated output to `jq`.  It depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

`| tee /dev/tty |` will write standard input to the console (on most systems) while still passing it on as standard output to the next command.

You might sometimes prefer `/dev/stderr` to write to standard error instead. For jq specifically, this may be sufficient:

```
| jq 'stderr | ...'
```

The [`stderr/0` function writes its input to standard error](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#stderr) and passes it on to the next filter. It will format the object (condensed, no highlighting), however, so that may or may not be what you want.